# Comparing DateTimes with Unspecified and UTC kinds

Tags: c#, datetime

I have 2 `DateTime` values:

date1 <- {15-07-13 20:45:10} with Kind = Unspecified

date2 <- {15-07-13 20:45:10} with Kind = UTC

When comparing these 2 dates, the 2 dates are equal.

```
if (DateTime.Compare(date1, date2)!=0)
    ...
```

**Can someone can explain why?**

A little bit more strange to me: when converting the date1 (which is Unspecified kind) to UTC, I clearly see that the date is different:

date1.ToUniversalTime() --> {15-07-13 18:45:10} with Kind = UTC

Comment: As a work-around you might want to write a custom comparer, something like `public class FullDateTimeEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<DateTime> { public override bool Equals(DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2) { return dt1.Kind == dt2.Kind && dt1 == dt2; } public override int GetHashCode(DateTime dt) { return dt.Kind.GetHashCode() ^ dt.GetHashCode(); } }`.

Comment: About your last point with the conversion.  Unspecified conversions are tricky...if you are converting ToLocalTime it assumes it is UTC.  And, vice-versa, if you are converting ToUniversalTime it assumes it is local.  So, either way a conversion happens.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Does someone can explain me why?

Yup. It's because [`DateTime` is a fundamentally broken type](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html), IMO. Basically the `Kind` isn't used in comparisons. Doing so would quite possibly have broken old code, and it's not always what you want. It was added on for .NET 1.1, and not always in a great way - it definitely wasn't fully integrated in every way you might have expected, as you've seen for comparisons.

As another example, even for a `Kind` of `Local` (which is meant to be the system local time zone) it's ignored for arithmetic, which means a call of `AddHours(1)` really only adds to the local time, rather than it representing *elapsed* time (which could end up being the same local time or two hours later in local time, around DST transitions).

My advice is just to avoid comparing `DateTime` values of different kinds in the first place. It's almost never what you want to do.

(Of course I'd also recommend using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), but that's a slightly different matter.)

Comment: `DateTimeOffset` will also work better here (for this specific purpose)

Comment: @MattJohnson: Potentially. Although for a `Kind` of `Unspecified`, `DateTimeOffset` is really weird...

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right.  See, it's so FUBAR even I get it wrong sometimes... :)

Comment: @MattJohnson: It's almost as if we need different types for "local date and time", "date and time in a particular time zone", "date and time just with a specific offset" etc. Why didn't that strike me before? ;)

Comment: LOL!   Speaking of which, I stumbled upon [something very interesting](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html) today.  Although I suppose [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/06/18/a-brief-history-of-datetime-anthony-moore.aspx) would be more relevant to this particular problem.

Answer (score 13):

From the documentation on [`DateTimeKind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx) (emphasis is mine):

> The members of the DateTimeKind enumeration are used in conversion
>   operations between local time and Coordinated Universal Time (UTC),
>   **but not in comparison or arithmetic operations**.

Comment: To elaborate on this, it means that if you live in the UTC-5 time zone and you compare a DateTime.Now to a DateTime.UtcNow, you'll see a TimeSpan of 5 hours as the difference.