# Github last commit value

Tags: c#, json, http, github, commit

So iv been doing a bit of further research, testing and such and got some help from a few people. and iv been able to come up with the following method:

```
public void GithubLastCommit(string apiLink)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");

            using (var response = client.GetAsync(apiLink).Result)
            {
                var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                dynamic commits = JArray.Parse(json);
                DateTime lastCommit = commits[0].commit.author.date;
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                int Days = (int)((now - lastCommit).TotalDays);
                int Hours = (int)((now - lastCommit).TotalHours);
                int Minutes = (int)((now - lastCommit).TotalMinutes);
                MessageBox.Show(Hours.ToString());
                if(Hours <=24)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Hours.ToString() + "Hours ago");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the apiLink im sending is just a random github i found to test this on: https://api.github.com/repos/Homebrew/homebrew/commits however i don't seem to be getting the correct value (of 1hour ago at the time of writing) and no matter what i change the index to it doesnt give me any correct values.. what might i be doing wrong?

Comment: What output are you currently getting and what do you expect?  I suspect that either you are parsing the JSON wrongly, or there is a problem with your date code.

Comment: i am currently receiving the entire json file from the api link provided, and it is being parsed into the JArray, in which i am selecting the first index and going through the sections available to reach the date. There is a hash or SHA code that is specific to each section or file added.. the main one i was looking for is the one with the SHA of 47146d.. etc which when looking into the api link is the very first one hence commits[0] i am then trying to retrieve the latest commit from this which follows through commit.author.date i am expecting 1 but get 11 for some reason.

Comment: Post what you receive and what you are getting.

Comment: using (var response = client.GetAsync(apiLink).Result)
            {
                var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
with this.. it retrieves all the text from the page that is linked.

far too much to paste in a comment, but its a json formatted text page. (it's an array of objects in json) so im selecting the first index which takes the first object and lets me access its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there is no standard for JSON dates, most JSON dates are expressed in terms of UTC.  The "Z" at the end of your time value, following [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC), indicates that this is so:

> ```
>     "date": "2015-04-27T03:58:52Z"
> ```

This is, in fact, [what Json.NET expects by default](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm), though you can configure it otherwise.  Thus you need to do:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

And your calculations should be correct.  That's because the `DateTime` subtraction operator [does not consider whether a `DateTime` is in local or UTC units](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and just assumes them to be in the same timezone [`Kind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) even if not.  More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661734/comparing-datetimes-with-unspecified-and-utc-kinds) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx).

**Update**

How does github format the "latest commit" time?  If one looks at the HTML source for your [homebrew](https://api.github.com/repos/Homebrew/homebrew/commits) page, one will see times like this:

> ```
>        <span class="css-truncate css-truncate-target"><time datetime="2015-04-27T15:31:05Z" is="time-ago">Apr 27, 2015</time></span>
> ```

So, what is this `"time-ago"` thing?  If one looks at the javascript for the page, one finds this:

> ```
> n.prototype.timeAgo = function () {
> var e = (new Date).getTime() - this.date.getTime(),
> t = Math.round(e / 1000),
> n = Math.round(t / 60),
> r = Math.round(n / 60),
> i = Math.round(r / 24),
> o = Math.round(i / 30),
> a = Math.round(o / 12);
> return 0 > e ? 'just now' : 10 > t ? 'just now' : 45 > t ? t + ' seconds ago' : 90 > t ? 'a minute ago' : 45 > n ? n + ' minutes ago' : 90 > n ? 'an hour ago' : 24 > r ? r + ' hours ago' : 36 > r ? 'a day ago' : 30 > i ? i + ' days ago' : 45 > i ? 'a month ago' : 12 > o ? o + ' months ago' : 18 > o ? 'a year ago' : a + ' years ago'
> },
> ```

So it looks as though, if the time difference is more than 36 hours but less that 30 days, they *round* (possibly up) to the nearest number of days.  You would need to duplicate this logic to get a similar result in your code.  Thus 3.5990 days would round to "4 days ago".

I found another version of the same logic here: [github/time-elements](https://github.com/github/time-elements)

Comment: YES i knew it had to be something like this! because of the time-difference i knew there had to be some sort of property i had to include to ensure it knew how to convert it or atleast know how to treat the now value. i will test this right away!

Comment: yup.. this is definately giving me a much closer value based on the last commit value compared to before, thanks alot :)

Comment: However i also tried this out on a few other githubs just to make sure it did work and i wasnt crazy :P this is the current stamp for my own repo 2015-04-23T21:46:10Z at the time of writing it is 2015-04-27T22:09:00 and yet when i use the above DateTime.UtcNow; it gives me in days.. 3.5990... and the github says last commit at 4 days.. as it is already past 4 days at the time of writing, shouldnt it be closer to 4.0547.. or something like this?

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @Darkshadow - answer updated.  If you are still having problems, can you [edit your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) to tell me how to reproduce the problem?  For instance, can you give me a sample of the JSON in question?  Also, what is the time on your computer in [ISO 8601 format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Roundtrip)?

Comment: i just realised while i was playing around and updating to git and everything and looking at the json response, is that the timestamp is different and that made me think about the timezone it uses, so i think that is having a weird effect on it.

But yeah i came to the same conclusion that they round up.. hence i've realised i can use the code i have in my question and simply round it up :P now that it's semi-accurate atleast :P

I appreciate all your help :) it's definately helped me get through and understand it alot better :)

My time in ISO 8601 format would be: 2015-04-28T03:13:05Z atm